# c-language data type arithmetic rules

Tags: c

in c-programming, if I use the variables k, X, Y, n in the equation below (where exp() is math constant e raised to (), pi = 3.14159..., and j = sqrt(-1)) and these variables are all declared as 64b double precision floating-pt numbers (where X is a complex number), the result for output will also be this data type.

```
output = k * exp(2*pi*j*X*Y/n)
```

Now, if I want to try to manage memory more intelligently, I'd like to make

k, Y, and n to be 32bit unsigned long int (0 to 4294967295), and

pi, j, and X to be 32bit float.

My question is, will the result for output be data type float (hopefully) or unsigned long int? That is, does C language have some default rules that intelligently takes care of multiplying a float and integer and returning the result as float, or must I manage that manually using type casting, etc? Just wondering if there's anything I need to worry about in such an operation, or if I can leave it to C to do everything intelligently behind the scenes.

Comment: It's a very bad way of thinking. Mixing integers with floats lead to serious performance penalties. Avoit it when possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can get kind of ugly. The compiler looks at the types of the operands for a *single* operation, and promotes both to the "larger" type (e.g., if one is `int` and the other `double`, it'll convert the `int` to `double`, then do the operation).

In your case, that could have some rather unexpected results. Right now you have: `2*pi*j*X*Y/n`. The operators group from left to right, so this is equivalent to `((((2*pi)*j)*X)*Y)/n`. In this case, that'll probably work out reasonably well -- one of the operands in the "first" operation is a float, so all the other operands will be converted to float as you want. If, however, you rearrange the operands (even in a way that seems equivalent in normal math) the result could be completely different. Just for example, if you rearranged it to `2*Y/n*pi*j*X`, the `2*Y/n` part would be done using *integer* arithmetic because `2`, `Y`, and `n` are all integers. This means the division would be done on integers, giving an integer result, and only *after* that integer result was obtained would that integer be converted to a float for multiplication by `pi`.

Bottom line: unless you're dealing with something like a large array so converting to smaller types is likely to really save quite a bit of memory, you're generally much better off keeping all the operands of the same type if possible. I'd also note that in this case, your attempt at "managing memory intelligently" probably won't do any good anyway -- on a typical current machine, a `long int` and a `float` are both 32 bits, so they both use the same amount of memory in any case. Also note that `exp` takes a `double` as its operand, so even if you do `float` math for the rest, it'll be promoted to a `double` anyway. Also note that conversions from `int` to `float` (and back) can be fairly slow.

If you're really only dealing with a half dozen variables or so, you're almost certainly best off leaving them as `double` and being done with it. Converting to a combination of `float` and `long` will save about 14 bytes of data storage, but then add (around) 14 bytes of extra instructions to handle all the conversions between `int`, `float`, and `double` at the right times, so you'll end up with slower code that uses just as much memory anyway.

Comment: Very interesting responses, thanks so much. And I thought I was helping things by carefully selecting int and floats. OK, so it seems the consensus is to keep everything either double for 64b precision, or everything float for 32 bit precision. Sound right?

Comment: @gkmath: yes, under the circumstances I'd probably leave them as doubles.

Comment: "The operators group from left to right, so this is equivalent to ((((2*pi)*j)*X)*Y)/n".  That is not true, the order of evaluation is implementation-defined and depends on the compiler. The compiler might as well evaluate the expression from right-to-left, and then you may get entirely different promotions. The programmer must make sure that the types of the operands will be the same no matter the order of evaluation.

Comment: @Lundin: While the order of evaluation is *not* defined, it doesn't matter -- the grouping *is* defined ("group from left to right" comes directly from §5.6/1 of the standard) and the promotions are based on the grouping, *not* on the order of evaluation.

Answer (score 8):

When doing arithmetic with floats and ints, it will always coerce it to a float. That is to say:

- float*float = float
- float*int = float
- int*float = float
- int*int=int

You will only receive "integer math" if all values are ints.

Comment: This answer is a bit misleading. You should replace "float" with "double". There is no such thing as promotion to float in C.

Comment: There is. These are known as the "usual arithmetic conversions". The ints in this post will be converted to float, not double. See ISO 9899:1999 6.3.1.8.

Answer (score 2):

The "usual arithmetic conversions" in the C language work like this on floats:

- If both operands are of the same type, then everything is fine.
- If one is double, the other is converted to double.
- Else if one is float, the other is converted to float.
- Else if they are both integers, the various rules of "integer promotions" apply.

A numeric constant "1" is regarded as int.
A numeric constant "1.0" is regarded as double.
A numeric constant "1.0f" is regarded as float.