# C - explanation for this answer

Tags: c

```
int main(void)
{ 
    float w = 8.456;
    int b = 3;

    printf("%d", (int)(b * w));

    return 0;
}
```

Can't seem to understand how does this equal to `25`, even though it's `int * float` and is displayed as an `int`, and what does `int` means in `printf` line... Isn't `int` multiply by `float` a `0`?

Comment: No int*float it a float. Why do you think that multiplying a int by a float is always 0?

Comment: No, an int multiplied by a float is NOT 0. The purpose of this exercise is to show you that casting to an int "chops off" the decimals

Comment: You may be thinking of int 1 divided by int 2 coming out as 0, instead of the 0.5 you had in mind.  But there's no general rule that when ints and floats collide, the result is automatically 0.  (That would be totally useless!)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`b*w` result is a `float` (=25.368) then you cast it to an `int` and it is truncated to `25`.

NB:
If you were expecting the result to be 24, both variable should be `ints`.

See: [c-language data type arithmetic rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801089/c-language-data-type-arithmetic-rules)

Answer (score 4):

As you multiply an integer with a floating point number, the so called "usual arithmetic conversions" (UAC) will take place. According to the UAC, if one of the operands is a `float` and the other is an integer then both operand will be converted to `float`: 3.0 * 8.456 = 25.368. Later, in the printf when it is converted to an int then fractional part will be truncated that's why the result will be 25.

Comment: Sorry, made a rather incomplete edit, I've rolled back. Have an upvote for good feelings.